# I can't leave the Iron Canopy after defeating Silitha in Darksiders

Tags: darksiders

I'm stuck in Darksiders and I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or if it is caused by a bug...

I have defeated Silitha, jumped two levels down and left through the spiderweb door. I stand before this chasm through which I originally entered the Iron Canopy (by being picked up by a nasty creature in a cut scene). There are now two blue orbs above the chasm. I use my grappling hook to cross the chasm. After walking for a few feet, the same cut scene starts again and I am transported back to the Iron Canopy.

Has anyone else experienced this? Did I forget something? My current quest says "Bring Silitha's heart to Samael" so I guess I did everything I needed to do in the Iron Canopy.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I remember there being a Vulgrimn Location in the Canopy which you should be able to use to get back to Samael via the Serpent Holes. It's been a few days since I did that part (playing through myself, I'm not much further along than you are), however.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Iron Canopy is one of the few locations without Vulgrim :-(

Comment: You've tried reloading a save already, right?

Comment: Yup, doesn't help.

Comment: @KristofClaes Did you manage to figure this out?

Answer (score 5):

After defeating silitha, you have to go down to silitha's body and there is a web door there that will lead you straight to ash lands. From there use serpent hole in vulgrimn to go back to Scalding Gallow to Sameal.